# Trying to parse a DateTime in C#

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, datetime

I am trying to parse a `DateTime` in C# and have the following lines of code:

```
string dt =Convert.ToString( DateTime.FromFileTime(e8.sts[counter8].TimeStamp));
string format = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss";
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(dt, format,CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

When I debug `dt` is coming in as `05/18/2011 09:25:17 AM` but I get an expection saying:

> String was not recognized as a valid
>   DateTime.

Comment: Looking at your comments, it is becoming clearer to me that *parsing* isn't the problem, and really you want to *output* a `DateTime` to a custom string format.  Can you please edit your question and add some clarification as to what you are looking for?  In particular, pushing it into MySql seems to be a requirement of yours, and you don't mention it in your question.

Answer (score 3):

Starting off, you have no need for the conversion.

`DateTime.FromFileTime(e8.sts[counter8].TimeStamp)` returns a `DateTime` already...

Even so, with the string you have provided, `DateTime.Parse(str)` will take care of you.

If you end up storing this value in a text file, and really are dead-set on using a custom format string to parse it (which you don't need to):

**The format you have:**

```
Day/Month/Year 24-hour:minute:second
```

But looking at your input date:

> 05/18/2011 09:25:17 AM

**You want:**

```
Month/Day/Year 12-hour:minutes:seconds AM/PM
```

The format for what you want is:

```
MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt
```

Comment: i will be read the datetime from the OPC server it will be return Timestamp in value "129501645169843750" so i will be convert this Timestamp to get the datetime.  i will be get the datetime in this format "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt" & i want to convert this time format in "MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss" format because when i will be stored the datetime in MYSQL database as datetime field & MYSQL not accept this format "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt"

Comment: @vrushali: The code sample you show asks how to parse a `DateTime`, not how to output one to a custom string format.  Did you want information on how to output to the custom `MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss` string format instead?

Answer (score 1):

Your DateTime is coming in as `MM-dd-yyyy` but you are trying to parse it as `dd-MM-yyyy`

Change your format string to `"MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss tt"`

You can tell this as `dt`, using your current format string, is trying to be parsed as the 5th day (dd) of the 18th month (MM) of 2011 (yyyy)...

**EDIT:**
Sorry, I completely missed the AM/PM designator, you need the `tt` part of the format string. This will handle the AM/PM part of the string

**EDIT 2:**
As per your most recent comment, you want to convert it into `MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss` string, the all you need to do is:

```
var outputString = DateTime.FromFileTime(e8.sts[counter8].TimeStamp).ToString("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
```

You already have the TimeStamp in a val;id .NET DateTime object, so all you need to do is perform a `.ToString()` with the required time format.

Comment: it will be display the same exception

Comment: i will be change like you tell me but it will be display the same exception

Comment: @vrushali, Anthony Pegram: I apologise. i completely missed the AM/PM designation in the `dt` string representation. I have updated my answer and deleted my stupid comment.

Comment: actually i want to convert the " MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt" this datetime format to this "MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss" because first format will be not accepted in the storing the MYSQL database datetime field because first used '/' i want '-'

Comment: @vrushali: I've updated my answer with the code to output it to a string in the correct format

Comment: it already is... When you do the `DateTime.FromFileTime(e8.sts[counter8].TimeStamp)`, you are getting a DateTime object. The debug string is just using the default `.ToString()` of the DateTime object (which is based on regional settings)

Comment: datetime dt=DateTime.FromFileTime(e8.sts[counter8].TimeStamp) .ToString("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss") like this it will be display the error Error Error Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.DateTime'

Answer (score 1):

Isn't this expected? Date `05/18/2011 09:25:17 AM` doesn't match your format string `dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss`. Your date is in format `MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt`.

Try this:

```
 DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Parse("05/18/2011 09:25:17 AM");
```

Comment: but i want to convert this date time format in dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss

Comment: @vrushali - so you have dates like this as an input `05/18/2011 09:25:17 AM` and you want to convert it to string like this `18-05-2011 09:25:17`?

Comment: @vrushali - Like this? `            var input = "05/18/2011 09:25:17 AM";
            DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Parse(input);
            string output = dateTime.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
`

Comment: but i want output in datetime variable not in string

Comment: @vrushali - I'm sorry, but you are confusing me. This code will do the best in parsing date time `DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Parse(inputDateTimeString);`. It create dateTime variable as you want.

Comment: but datetime variable take the system date format is it right & my datetime format is "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt" but this format not stored in the MYSQL database datetime field because MYSQL format is "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss" so i want MYSQL format but date time format change though the coding not in the system

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any reason for the conversion.  Just use:

```
DateTime.FromFileTime(e8.sts[counter8].TimeStamp)
```

Comment: i will be read the datetime from the OPC server it will be return Timestamp in value "129501645169843750" so i will be convert this Timestamp to get the datetime. i will be get the datetime in this format "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt" & i want to convert this time format in "MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss" format because when i will be stored the datetime in MYSQL database as datetime field & MYSQL not accept this format "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt"

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime parsed = DateTime.ParseExact(dt,"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 0):

s many of the others have explained here, the format needs to be changed. However even when I tried the formats they have suggested, I still received the same error that you did. Eventually I hit upon the right format to get successful results.

The format should be:

```
string format = "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt";
```

because you are specifying time pattern such as AM. If the month is given as single digit, eg: 5, then MM should be replaced with M. I used slash instead of hypen between the dates because that's how the original date  had been given.